# GridLayout inside a LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-gridlayout

I want to put a Gridlayout inside a LinearLayout due to some complex requirement. My question is, is it recommended? if so how to do it properly?

Answer (score 1):

**Is it recommended ?**

> From [Optimizing Layout](http://developer.android.com/intl/in/training/improving-layouts/optimizing-layout.html)
>
> - Deep layouts - Layouts with too much nesting are bad for performance.    **Consider using flatter layouts such as RelativeLayout
>     or GridLayout    to improve performance**. The default maximum depth is
>     10.
> - Use compound drawables - A LinearLayout which contains an ImageView    and a TextView can be more efficiently handled as a compound drawable.

Comment: Do you want more justificaion? @user3313952

Answer (score 0):

-- Simple and efficient way to do :

```
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/gridViewFont"
            android:numColumns="2"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:columnWidth="100dp"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: That's a GridView, which is not the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="3dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/grid_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
        android:verticalSpacing="1dp"
        android:numColumns="2" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: That's a GridView, which is not the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

yes, It is recommended

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/grid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
        android:verticalSpacing="1dp"
        android:numColumns="2" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: That's a GridView, which is not the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="4dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

    <GridView
            android:id="@+id/gridView1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/mainLinearLayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:columnWidth="100dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
            android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:numColumns="2"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth">
        </GridView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: That's a GridView, which is not the same thing.